# Rails devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

How can I modify attributes of User instance before save in custom registrations controller, inherited from Devise::RegistrationsController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself. In your model do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_attributes

    def set_attributes
       // Change the attributes to what you like
    end
end
```

Comment: Hm..the problem is to change attribute ony by registering a user. It is used to create account for user.

Comment: Then you can use `before_create` instead of `before_save`